# Latest version installed but not being used

Tags: python, python3, debian-buster

I've been trying to upgrade python to 3.7 on a Debian buster server. If I type `python3 --version` it returns `python 3.6.1`. However, if I run `sudo apt install python3` it returns the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.7.3-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Likewise running `sudo apt-get install python3.7` give the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3.7 is already the newest version (3.7.3-2).
python3.7 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So, it would appear that Python 3.7 is installed but why is it returning the version in use as 3.6.1 ?

Any ideas how I can fix this to use python 3.7 ?

Comment: Have you looked into https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives? Maybe your system wasn't updated to use the new version as the default for python3.

Comment: Hi Phill, if this was the answer that helped you, you might want to formulate an answer to your own question and mark it as the answer. Alternatively I can write an answer, which you could mark as the answer. Anyways if someone finds this post, it might be helpful for them to find a clear answer.